# set default selected node in richfaces4 tree

Tags: java, jsf, tree, richfaces

I'm using richfaces 4.2.2. I have a tree component on my page. Every time I enter the page I need the root node to be selected by default. I have some troubles to acomplish this. Any help will be appreciated.